# Pass type parameter through protocols?

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to implement a solution for following use case, using generics:

There's a dialog class, dialog is used to select an item from a list. Dialog has to be generic, so I created a protocol for the items, which delivers e.g. the label used in the list, and a protocol for the "delegate", to handle a clicked item.

The dialog passes the clicked item to the delegate. Since I'm using generics, the idea is that I have not to use casting in order to get the item (more exactly the model object wrapped in the item) with the correct type. I prepared a self-contained example in a playground file, to illustrate what I mean.

This doesn't compile, since I'm not casting the item down.

I can solve this with Java - just implemented it, there DialogListener and DialogItem have type parameter `<T>`, so I can pass `<Student>` int the declaration / instantiation and in the listener I receive parameter `DialogItem<Student>` and thus don't need to downcast.

I suspect it might not be possible to do this in in Swift since I don't see anything usable in the doc, but I hope I'm wrong...

Just to make it clear, the question is, how can I implement this, as a generic solution, without having to use any casting?

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Model class

class Student {
    let name:String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Dialog item, this wraps the model class

protocol DialogItem {

    typealias T

    func getLabel() -> String

    func getModel() -> T
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implementation of dialog item "wrapper" for student

class StudentDialogItem : DialogItem {

    let student:Student

    init(student:Student) {
        self.student = student
    }

    func getLabel() -> String {
        return student.name
    }

    func getModel() -> Student {
        return student
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Listener
// ---> how can I pass T to DialogListener and then to DialogItem, to get items with correct type?

protocol DialogListener {


    func onItemSelected(item:DialogItem)
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Dialog, with "dummy" functionality

class ItemSelectionDialog {
    let items:[DialogItem]
    let listener:DialogListener

    init (items:[DialogItem], listener:DialogListener) {
        self.items = items
        self.listener = listener
    }

    func show() {
        for item in items {
            println(item.getLabel())
        }
    }

    func simulateClick(index:Int) {
        listener.onItemSelected(items[index])
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implementation of dialog listener

class DialogListenerImpl : DialogListener {

    func onItemSelected(item: DialogItem)  {
        let student:Student = item.getModel() //<---- DialogItem doesn't have type information, compiler doesn't even seem to recognise getModel()!
        //do something with student
        println("Selected a student!, name: " + student.name)
    }
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let items:[Student] = [Student(name: "Student1-name"), Student(name: "Student2-name"), Student(name: "Student3-name")]

let listener = DialogListenerImpl()

let studentDialogItems:[StudentDialogItem] = items.map({StudentDialogItem(student: $0)})

let dialog = ItemSelectionDialog(items: studentDialogItems, listener: listener)

dialog.show()

dialog.simulateClick(1)
```

And this is the Java code, that works as I want:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Model class

class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Dialog item, this wraps the model class

class StudentDialogItem implements DialogItem<Student> {

    private Student student;

    public StudentDialogItem(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return student.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Student getModel() {
        return student;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Implementation of dialog item "wrapper" for student

interface DialogItem<T> {

    String getLabel();

    T getModel();   
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Listener

interface DialogListener<T> {

    void onItemSelected(DialogItem<T> item);    
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Dialog, with "dummy" functionality

class ItemSelectionDialog<T> {

    private List<DialogItem<T>> items;
    private DialogListener<T> listener;

    public ItemSelectionDialog(List<DialogItem<T>> items, DialogListener<T> listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.listener = listener; 
    }

    public void show() {
        for (DialogItem<T> item : items) {
            System.out.println(item.getLabel());
        }
    }

    //Simulate click
    public void simulateClick(int index) {

        listener.onItemSelected(items.get(index));
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Implementation of dialog listener

class DialogListenerImpl implements DialogListener<Student> {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(DialogItem<Student> item) {
        Student student = item.getModel();              
        //do something with student
        System.out.println("Selected a student!, name: " + student.getName());
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(new Student("Student1-name"), new Student("Student2-name"), new Student("Student3-name"));

        DialogListener<Student> listener = new DialogListenerImpl();

        //Wrap the model objects in dialog items
        List<DialogItem<Student>> studentDialogItems = new ArrayList<DialogItem<Student>>();
        for (Student student : students) {
            studentDialogItems.add(new StudentDialogItem(student));
        }

        ItemSelectionDialog<Student> dialog = new ItemSelectionDialog<Student>(studentDialogItems, listener);

        dialog.show();

        dialog.simulateClick(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic types in protocols are not supported.  But the fact that `item.getModel()` returns a `Student` is known in both your Java and Swift code within the implementations of `onSelectedItem`.  In the Java code you can state it as part of the generic type system as `onItemSelected(DialogItem<Student> item)`.  In the Swift code you could use:

```
let student:Student = item.getModel() as Student
```

which is unsatisfying, but works.

Comment: Well, I asked explicitly for a solution *without casting*. The point of generics is to do the checks at compile time. With the Java version the compiler will complain if I use a wrong type in DialogListenerImpl. With casting if I use the wrong type it will crash at runtime.

Comment: Right, sorry, missed that.  Note that there is consistency however.  You define DialogItem and DialogItemListener as the generic parts of your Swift code and then Student, StudentDialogItem and StudentDialogItemListener (which you called DialogListenerImpl) as the specifically types parts.

Comment: Yes, but as you say it's unsatisfying. I understood from the programming guide that protocols "support generics" using typealias, but this seems to be very limited.